# Simple Phase Shift for Removing Instrument Response

Tags: matlab, fft

So I have a simple program where I want to shift a simple sine function pi/2. Now I knwo this would be extremely easy by just inserting a bias (i.e. A*sin(2*pi*frequency + bias). But this program is a simple way to test a theory. I need to shift complicated magnetic data, but the shift is frequency dependent. So to figure out how to do that I just want to shift this sin wave by a set shift, but I want to do it in the frequency domain. While the code below doesn't show any errors, it does not shift the data properly and effects magnitude.  Code is below. Thank you!

```
clear all
time = 1:0.01:2*pi; %Create time vector
mag = sin(2*pi*time);
Y = fft(mag); %transform
Pnewr = pi/2;
%t = angle(mag);
t = imag(Y);
%t_fin = t-Pnewr; %Subtract the pahse delay from the original phase vector
R=real(Y);
I=t;
k = I./R
Phi = tan(k);
PhiFinal = Phi-Pnewr;
PhiFinal = PhiFinal'
IFinal = R * atan(PhiFinal);
spec=complex(R,IFinal);
Finalspec = ifft(spec); %Invert the transform
Final = Finalspec;
plot(time,mag);
hold on
plot(time,Final,'r')
grid on
```

Comment: Thank you.  I actually saw that as well and made the change but the result is even stranger.  Here's the plotted graph with tan replaced with a atan: http://imgur.com/mD5Ggjl

Comment: [Hilbert transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform)?

Comment: In Matlab using [`hilbert`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/hilbert.html): `Final = imag(hilbert(mag));`. Whole numbers of periods will be helpful in avoiding edge effects.

Comment: @IKeneally, I followed your link.  It sure looks phase shifted to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one thing you are not recombining imaginary and real components properly, since

```
PhiFinal = PhiFinal'
IFinal = R * atan(PhiFinal);
```

is effectively a dot product, not an element by element product. In general it doesn't look like you are making correct use of the complex relationships. The following generates a clean phase shift:

```
time = 1:0.01:2*pi; 
mag = sin(2*pi*time);
Y = fft(mag); %transform

Pnewr = pi/2;

R = real(Y);
I = imag(Y);

It = abs(Y);
% It = sqrt(I.^2 + R.^2);

Phi= angle(Y); % <-- using matlab function, equivalent to `Phi = atan2(I, R);`

k = I./R;
Phi0 = atan(k);

figure, subplot(121), plot(Phi0,Phi,'.'), xlabel('Phi from tan'), ylabel('Phi from ''angle'''), grid on, axis('tight')

PhiFinal = Phi-Pnewr; % <-- phase shift

IFinal = It .* sin(PhiFinal);
RFinal = It .* cos(PhiFinal);
spec= RFinal + 1i*IFinal;
Final = ifft(spec); %Invert the transform

subplot(122)
plot(time,mag);
hold on
plot(time,real(Final),'r')
plot(time,imag(Final),'r:')
grid on
axis('tight')
legend('Initial','Final'),xlabel('t'), ylabel('I')

mag*mag'   % <-- check that total power is conserved
Final*Final'
```

These figures show the phase as computed with `tan` vs matlab's `angle` (which uses `atan2`), and the results of the phase shift (right panel):

[image]